# Facebook login app error "Given URL is not allowed"

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm trying to use python social auth with Django to add Facebook log in for my app. I have my App ID and secret in my settings file, yes yes. I'm just using the Django example for python social auth, uploaded at a subdomain.

But I get the following error:

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

My app lives at a subdomain, not localhost. I've tried various configurations in the App Domains and Website URL fields. Basically base domain and subdomain in all configurations. Namespace and Email are empty..?

Every answer I've found pertaining to this error just says to "Just add the Website URL!" But it's not working for me. Is there something I am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh lordy, hooray for answering your own question.

I had pasted the Google redirect url into Settings > Advanced > Redirect URIs instead of the Facebook one (https://domain.com/complete/facebook/). WOOPS.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for ages and I finally didn't find it on the web but had to figure it out myself, so MAYBE HOPEFULLY I can help sb with this. I'm using python-social-auth and I have it working under the URL mysite.com:8000/login/facebook. So I tried to enter that to every darned field in that FB API but with absolutely no luck. The solution appeared in the URL where FB returned the error. It looks sth like this: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&state=5q29qH6sUnl6MVAZxPFPgoEbdlsF5GkD&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsportest.com%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3D5q29qH6sUnl6MVAZxPFPgoEbdlsF5GkD&client_id=1626606360913209`

So I took `http%3A%2F%2Fsportest.com%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3D5q29qH6sUnl6MVAZxPFPgoEbdlsF5GkD` part out of it and decoded it using [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Result: `http://sportest.com:8000/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=5q29qH6sUnl6MVAZxPFPgoEbdlsF5GkD`

Now that - that you'll wanna enter in the **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** and **Site URL** fields in the FB API. It werks, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.Resolve it by using the steps below

1. Go to Settings->Basic->Add Platform->Android
2. You will be asked to enter a package name and hash key
3. Generate a hash key as mentioned here 
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
4. Enter the package name and hash key and save the changes
5. Go to Advanced Tab->Enter the url in Valid OAuth redirect URIs.
6. Save Changes and run the app.The error will not appear again